Cannot get resources
I am trying to read a image from the resources directory using
new DataInputStream(Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(FilePack.class, "/resources/0.png"));

but the InputStream is null and throws the following error message
resources cannont be nested in directories in Codename One! Invalid resource: : /resources/0.png

The path of the resources folder is
common/src/resources and of the Main class with 0.png is common/src/main/game/Main.java
How can I fix it?

Have you considered putting the image file into the /raw or /assets directory?
This should make it easier to access. No need to use reflection at all.

Place images in common/src/main/resources directory.
Then change
Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(FilePack.class, "/resources/0.png");

to
Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(FilePack.class, "/0.png");

Note, the generated project from https://start.codenameone.com doesn't have resources directory by default. You should create it at common/src/main/ and place images there.
